# No sound using CallKit - how do I know the other side answers, held, or end the call?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, callkit

I am using the following code to test CallKit. I can invoke an outgoing call from the "A" device and by use of VoIP to receive UUID invoke incoming function on the "B" device. But when I press answer call button on "B", no sound ("A" & "B") occurs. I don't get any delegate callback on "A" to know other side any action.

How can I know the callback status of “B” device is answer, reject, held or end call on "A" device?

Is using the VoIP method for notifying device "A" or am I missing a step?

#### File ProviderDelegate.swift

```
import Foundation
import CallKit

class ProviderDelegate: NSObject, CXProviderDelegate {
    static let sharedInstance = ProviderDelegate()
    var provider: CXProvider!
    var controller: CXCallController!

    override init() {
        controller = CXCallController()

        let providerConfiguration = CXProviderConfiguration(localizedName: "My App name")
        providerConfiguration.supportsVideo = true
        providerConfiguration.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 1
        providerConfiguration.supportedHandleTypes = [.generic]

        provider = CXProvider(configuration: providerConfiguration)

        super.init()

        provider.setDelegate(self, queue: nil)
    }

    func incomingCall(uuid: UUID) {
        let update = CXCallUpdate()
        update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: "Any name")
        provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: update, completion: { error in })
    }

    func outgoingCall(uuid: UUID) {
        let transaction = CXTransaction(action: CXStartCallAction(call: uuid, handle: CXHandle(type: .generic, value: "Any name")))
        controller.request(transaction, completion: { error in })
    }

    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {
        print ("CXAnswerCallAction")
        configureAudioSession()
        action.fulfill()
    }

    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXEndCallAction) {
        print ("CXEndCallAction")
        action.fulfill()
    }

    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXSetHeldCallAction) {
        print ("CXSetHeldCallAction")
        action.fulfill()
    }

    func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXStartCallAction) {
        print ("CXStartCallAction")
        configureAudioSession()

        provider.reportOutgoingCall(with: action.uuid, startedConnectingAt: nil)
        provider.reportOutgoingCall(with: action.uuid, connectedAt: nil)
        action.fulfill()
    }

    func providerDidReset(_ provider: CXProvider) {
        print ("Distory")
    }
}
```

#### File Audio.swift

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

func configureAudioSession() {
    print("Configuring audio session")
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        try session.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat)
        try session.setActive(true)
    } 
    catch (let error) {
        print("Error while configuring audio session: \(error)")
    }
}

func startAudio() {
    print("Starting audio")
}

func stopAudio() {
    print("Stopping audio")
}
```

#### Edit

Use apple native VOIP service to send and receive UUID

#### File AppDelegate.swift

```
let providerDelegate = ProviderDelegate.sharedInstance

func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didReceiveIncomingPushWith payload: PKPushPayload, for type: PKPushType, completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let payloadDict = payload.dictionaryPayload["aps"] as! NSDictionary
    let uuid = payloadDict.object(forKey: "uuid") as! String

    providerDelegate.incomingCall(uuid: UUID.init(uuidString: uuid)!)
}
```

Comment: which library or framework you are using for voip calling? If you are not using any, then you misunderstood the purpose of callkit.

Comment: According to your reply, Callkit should be come with third party library or framework. Do you have any suggest library or framework. I need to make a voice chat.

Comment: Can i use apple native VOIP service to do it?Sorry, I don’t know much.